# KVM - Share Vm's Internet access with host (reversed use case)

Tags: networking, kvm, nat

So if your traffic "must" go via Windows.

1. Setup Linux on PC
2. Create Windows VM
3. VM gets Wifi Dongle (USB-Redirect)

Atm, the host (linux) has no internet access. Is there a way to create a subnet on windows and then share it with the linux host? So the opposite of what u usually do when you use NAT to let the VMs access the host network?